# Breakable vboxes

Tags: tex-core, page-breaking, boxes

In Plain TeX how can I make vboxes breakable, and can I handle/measure them separately? What I'm trying to do, is that I have a portion of text, that is treated separately (no indention, narrower, coloured background, with the use of `\hrule`/`\vrule`) and make it breakable.

Additionally I'm interested in how to brake automatically hboxes

Comment: hboxes cannot break - that is rather the point of them!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `\vbox` is by itself not breakable. But assigning it to a box register allows TeX to split it with the `\vsplit` operation.

```
\newbox\totalbox
\newbox\partialbox
\newdimen\partialboxdim
\setbox\totalbox=\vbox{<settings><text>}
<measurements setting \partialboxdim to the available space>
\setbox\partialbox=\vsplit\totalbox to \partialdim
\addcoloredbackground{\unvbox\partialbox}
<measurements setting \partialboxdim to the available space>
...
```

This is the scheme, you have to provide the \addcoloredbackground macro and the measurements, probably based on `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal`. The TeXbook and TeX by Topic have examples about `\vsplit`.

Let's expand a bit; I assume you have a `\colorthisbox` macro that adds a colored background to a box and requirese 3pt of extra space above and below it. The strategy is first to gather the text to be boxed:

```
\newbox\totalbox
\newbox\partialbox
\newdimen\partialboxdim
\def\startcoloredbox{\par\bigskip
\setbox\totalbox=\vbox\bgroup\advance\hsize by -6pt}
\def\endcoloredbox{\egroup\splitcoloredbox}
```

At this point we have all the text; now we start the splitting:

```
\def\splitcoloredbox{\ifvoid\totalbox\finishcoloredbox
  \else\continuesplitting\fi}
\def\finishcoloredbox{\bigskip}
```

The macro `\finishcoloredbox` should provide the finishing touches, I've only put a `\bigskip`. The macro `\continuesplitting` is the heart of the process: it first measures the available space, but first of all it places a `\null` box in the main vertical list, because when the current page is empty, `\pagegoal` equals `\maxdimen`. The `6pt` is the extra space reserved for printing the colored box. If the (remaining) part of box `\totalbox` is less high than the available space, we simply set box `\partialbox` to it, otherwise we split off from `\totalbox` what is necessary to fill the available space; then we pass the control to `\colorthisbox`, but we add `\eject` in the second case, since we are sure that we have reached the bottom of a page and we want to start at a fresh one with `\pagetotal=0pt`. After processing we call `\splitcoloredbox` again.

```
\def\continuesplitting{\null % In case this starts a new page
  \dimen255=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\pageshrink-6pt\relax
  \ifdim\ht\totalbox<\dimen255
    \setbox\partialbox=\box\totalbox
    \colorthisbox
  \else
    \setbox\partialbox=\vsplit\totalbox to\dimen255
    \colorthisbox\eject
  \fi
  \splitcoloredbox}
```

Here is the definition of `\colorthisbox` I used for testing; it's important that it encloses everything in a box (`\hbox` or `\vbox`) in order not to start horizontal mode.

```
\def\colorthisbox{\hbox{\fbox{\vbox{\unvbox\partialbox}}}}
```

(yes, the testing was done in LaTeX, because of `\lipsum`). The `\vbox{\unvbox\partialbox}` part is important because it avoids underfull boxes.

Comment: @egreg: Am I correct in thinking that this approach means that splitting has to come before adding background colour?

Comment: @Joseph: I think this is the easiest way, but I'm no expert in pdfTeX color management.

Comment: @egreg: neither am I. A quick look at `color.sty` shows me that `\colorbox` is implemented using a rule the size of the box, which of course can't then be split. So if the colour goes in before splitting it would have to be done some other way.

Comment: @Joseph: so it's better to delay the coloring

Comment: Well that does not solve the underfull boxes, and also seems awkward, when it splits at the first line, but it does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam: you can add a check for the minumum height of the split box: `\ifdim\dimen255<3\baselineskip ...\else ...\fi`

Comment: You write that pagetotal is maxdimen at the top of a page, but isn't it actually pagegoal that is maxdimen, and pagetotal is 0pt?

Comment: @RobertR You're right! I'll fix. From the description it was clear I was talking about `\pagegoal`, but, who knows why, `goal` became `total` when typing.

Answer (score 3):

> An experiment

This approach of breaking vertical boxes helped me. I tried to figure out how many lines I am dealing with in a block. I am usually using the `lineno` package for that and its `\linelabel` and `\lineref` commands. These commands are similar to their `\label` and `\ref` counterparts. I am able to get a number of lines using this method. If I need a number of section I use common `\label` next to the `\linelabel` command.

However, when I am typesetting via `\parbox`, this approach is not working. We can list line numbers using the internal command `\internallinenumbers` from the `lineno` package but I don't know how to refer to them.

Therefore, I saved my paragraph into a vertical box and started to splitting lines up by `\baselineskip`. Once the height of that box  (`\myboxtemp`) is equal to `0pt` I am done. I am enclosing an example where I rotated and coloured the lines differently. Number of lines is stored in the counter named `\mycounter`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newdimen\mujtemp
\mujtemp=\textwidth
\advance\mujtemp by -35mm

\section{My section}
\linenumbers
My first line.\par My second line.\linelabel{myfavoriteline}\label{mysection}
\par My third line.\par
\nolinenumbers

I am referring to line~\lineref{myfavoriteline}, section~\ref{mysection} on page~\pageref{myfavoriteline}.
\bigskip

\newsavebox{\mojkovo}%
\savebox{\mojkovo}{\parbox{\mujtemp}{%
   \kant[1]%
   \internallinenumbers
   }}%
\usebox{\mojkovo}
\bigskip

\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\usebox{\mojkovo}}
width \the\wd\mybox, height \the\ht\mybox, depth \the\dp\mybox
\vspace{6mm}\par

\setbox\mybox=\vbox to \vsize{\rightskip=35mm\kant[1]}%
\newbox\myboxtemp
\newcount\mycounter\mycounter=0%
\loop
\advance\mycounter by 1%
\setbox\myboxtemp=\vsplit\mybox to \baselineskip%

\makebox[35mm][l]{\ifnum\mycounter<10 0\fi
\the\mycounter---\the\ht\myboxtemp\ \the\dp\myboxtemp\  }
\ifnum\ht\myboxtemp=0 There are no more lines!\fi
{\color{green}\vbox to 1\baselineskip
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\pgfmathparse{8*\the\mycounter+30}
\let\myaddition=\pgfmathresult
\node[anchor=west, rotate=2.5*\the\mycounter, color=green!50!black!\myaddition]{\usebox\myboxtemp};
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}\par%
\ifnum\mycounter<18\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe1]

**Edit:** This is my best shot of rewriting and cutting down the code into Plain TeX format. We couldn't use `\newsavebox`, `\savebox` and `\usebox` commands as these are the LaTeX format commands, please see `latex.ltx` for more details. I didn't know how to load a paragraph from the `kantlipsum` package, so I extracted a small portion of their code. I enclose the source code and a page preview.

```
%! pdftex boxes-plain.tex
\hsize=345pt % Taken from LaTeX...
\parindent=0pt
{\bf From kantlipsum package:}\par\vskip2mm
\def\mypara{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena. Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in space and time are what first give rise to human reason.}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\rightskip=35mm\mypara}
\copy\mybox
\vskip2mm
\newbox\myboxtemp
\newcount\mycounter
\mycounter=0
\loop
  \advance\mycounter by 1%
  \setbox\myboxtemp=\vsplit\mybox to \baselineskip
  \hbox to\hsize{Line number \the\mycounter\hfill}%
  \copy\myboxtemp
\ifnum\ht\myboxtemp=0{\it There are no more lines! I am escaping from the loop.}\fi
\ifnum\ht\myboxtemp>0\repeat
\bye
```

[image: mwe2]

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a plain-[Xe]TeX solution. I did not dive in your solution yet, but I'll check it out when I'm there.

Comment: Yes, it happens to me quite often, I am mixing LaTeX commands with the TeX primitives. I have used the `\newsavebox` in the first part of the example which is defined in the `latex.ltx` file, that part is not going to work for you right away. This is working for me `\newbox\mybox\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\rightskip=35mm typeset material}`.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this code, helped me a lot. Cheers!