# How to split a minipage?

Tags: macros

How can I measure the height of a minipage and then split and store the text into two macros? The first macro must store the text that does not exceed a certain limit say `\maxheight` and the second to store the balance of the text. Ideally I would like the split to happen at a word break.

Comment: Measuring the height of a `minipage` should not be a problem. However, typesetting up to some height restriction and then "un-typesetting" it into a macro is perhaps a task for `lualatex`. May I ask what the end use is?

Comment: @Werner How would lualatex split it? I am just trying to truncate a textblock containing text to a certain height. I thought I would save the truncated part and just `\show` it to see the additional text.

Comment: I am not familiar with `lualatex`, but it provides a more code-like approach to TeX. (La)TeX's approach to such a problem would typically be far less elegant, in my opinion.

Comment: @Werner I tried `\vsplit`, but I don't know enough TeX to achieve any results.

Comment: There is an experimental `splitbox` in `adjustbox` but it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really store the *text* into two macros, but rather the two pieces of the typeset `minipage` into two box registers.

However this *can't* be done with `minipage`, but only with lower level commands: `\vbox` and `\vsplit`.

You can look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20903/4427) or at the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes)

If neither of them satisfy you, then you can be more precise in your question about your purposes.