# TikZ frame paragraph span across pages in ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, framed, context-mkiv

I tried to reproduce the following example in ConTeXt:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/framed-tikz/

How can I substitute the LaTeX `framed` package, that is make the frame span across multiple pages?
(Resigning from TikZ is not an option as I have already designed my own frame.)

Comment: The `mdframed` packaged

Comment: @dustin: It's context

Comment: Take a look at [`textbackgrounds`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TextBackground#Example:_multi-page_backgrounded_text) in the ConTeXt garden.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The textbackground's `backgrounds` key does not accept overlays. MetaPost overlays can be hooked in using the `mp` and `method` keys. I don't see any simple way to use TikZ graphics with the textbackground mechanism.

Comment: Use the `background` mechansim. @Macro, in the past i have used textbackgrounds with overlays, so I don't know if something has changed recently.

Comment: @Aditya It used to work in the past, yes. But I can't get it to work with a current MkIV. Maybe it's a bug or the interface has changed.

Comment: @Marco: If `background` key doesn't work with `textbackground`, then it is surely a bug.

Comment: @Aditya Actually I cannot confirm that backgrounds worked with overlays in textbackgrounds, I just checked some old code. It might be by design since textbackgrounds allow for page breaks. But I'll move the discussion to the mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background` mechanism for this. You can get the width and height of the box using `\overlaywidth` and `\overlayheight`. Here is an example:

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\startsetups tikz:frame
  \starttikzpicture 
    \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (0,0) -- (0, \overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth, \overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth,0) -- cycle;
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopsetups 

\defineoverlay[tikzframe][\setups{tikz:frame}]

\definebackground[tikzframe][background=tikzframe]

\starttext

\starttikzframe
  \dorecurse{10}{\input knuth \endgraf}
\stoptikzframe

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**EDIT**: In a comment, @user19041 asked if it is possible to change the background depending on the *state* of the splitting. ConTeXt does have an internal macro `\backgroundsplitmode` that keeps track of how the `\vbox` is being split. Unfortunately, it does not differentiate between the case when the vbox does not need to be split, and the case when the vbox is split but we are at the last page. It is easy to differentiate between these two (provided you are not nesting such frames; in that case, we'll need to define a new counter for each nested level). The example below illustrates how this is done. I have just changed the background color to illustrate the concept.

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\setnewconstant\tikzbackgroundstate\zerocount

\definecolor[backgroundcolor][lightgray]

\startsetups tikz:frame
  \starttikzpicture 
    \ifcase \backgroundsplitmode
      % Case 0: no split or last page
      \ifcase\tikzbackgroundstate
        % The frame does not split across pages
        \definecolor[backgroundcolor][lightgray]
      \else
        % Last page of a split frame
        \definecolor[backgroundcolor][red]
      \fi \or 
      % Case 1: split to max height, always middle page
        \definecolor[backgroundcolor][yellow]
        \global\tikzbackgroundstate=\plusone
      \else
      % Case 2: split to partial height. Always first page
        \definecolor[backgroundcolor][green]
        \global\tikzbackgroundstate=\plustwo
      \fi
        \filldraw[fill=backgroundcolor] (0,0) -- (0, \overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth, \overlayheight) -- (\overlaywidth,0) -- cycle;
  \stoptikzpicture
\stopsetups 

\defineoverlay[tikzframe][\setups{tikz:frame}]

\definebackground[tikzinternalframe][background=tikzframe]

\define\starttikzframe
    {\dosingleargument\dostarttikzframe}

\def\dostarttikzframe[#1]%
    {\tikzbackgroundstate=\zerocount
     \starttikzinternalframe[#1]}

\define\stoptikzframe{\stoptikzinternalframe}



\starttext

\starttikzframe
\input ward
\stoptikzframe

\blank[big]

\starttikzframe
  \dorecurse{11}{\input knuth \endgraf}
\stoptikzframe



\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: The other solution (posted by myself) makes it quite easy to implement different frame shapes in different contexts (to be specific: lack of top and/or bottom frame if the content starts/ends on another page). Is there any way to do it with the background mechanism?
Edit: I figured out that I can manually add horizontal lines at the beginning and the end of the content (and get rid of them anywhere else), but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Changing the frame depending on context is easy to do with metapost backgrounds (e.g., see [this thread](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/70408/) in the mailing list). I'll have to check if there are other hooks that can be used with tikz.

Comment: @user19041: See my edit

Answer (score 1):

My current draft solution is based on the answer to [Breakable vboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes):

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\pgfdeclarelayer {background}
\pgfsetlayers {background,main}

\newbox\totalbox
\newbox\partialbox
\newdimen\partialboxdim

\def\startframedbox{\par\bigskip
\setbox\totalbox=\vbox\bgroup\advance\hsize by -8pt}
\def\endframedbox{\egroup\splitframedbox}

\def\splitframedbox{\ifvoid\totalbox\finishframedbox
  \else\continuesplitting\fi}
\def\finishframedbox{\bigskip}

\newdimen\Distance

\def\continuesplitting{\null%
  \Distance=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\pageshrink-6pt\relax
  \ifdim\ht\totalbox<\Distance
    \setbox\partialbox=\box\totalbox
    \framethisbox
  \else
    \setbox\partialbox=\vsplit\totalbox to\dimexpr\Distance-5pt\relax
    \framethisbox
    \vfill\page
  \fi
  \splitframedbox}

\def\framethisbox{%
\starttikzpicture
    \node (A) {\hbox{\vbox{\unvbox\partialbox}}};
    \startpgfonlayer{background}
        \filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (A.north east) -- (A.north west) -- (A.south west) -- (A.south east) -- cycle;
    \stoppgfonlayer{background}
\stoptikzpicture%
}

\starttext

\input knuth

\startframedbox
  \dorecurse{15}{\input knuth\par}
\endframedbox

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

This code draws a thin frame around the text and adds a gray background, but any valid TikZ code should work.

Comment: Also see `pack-bck.mkvi` for a different vbox splitting algorithm.