# ocgx2 does not work with sumatra, but ocgx does

Tags: sumatrapdf, ocg

According to this artivle [Can I automatically split an ocg environment over page breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131193/can-i-automatically-split-an-ocg-environment-over-page-breaks/280146#280146) a new pages was introduced by AlexG

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{ocgx2}[2015/11/23]
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
first example.
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
second example.
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 3}{ocg3}{0}
third example. 
\end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Expecting empty page, also in Sumatra 2.5.2
If you use ocgx the page IS empty, im Sumatra also as in Acrobat.
If you use ocgx2 the page is empty in Acrobat Reader only, but all conents will be displayed at sumatra reader.
If you use current sumatra 3.1.1 no changes are seen.

to make it clear: I am not expecting to toggle any content in sumatra, but I am expecting that nothing will be displayed first, (as ocgx does).

Seems to me like a bug?

Comment: This is indeed a bug which has been fixed in `pdfbase.sty` v. 0.4 `[2016/02/13]` (part of `media9`) on which `ocgx2` depends. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: I am voting to close this question, because it is about a bug that has been fixed meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, its fixed. Agree to close.