# Why can I not vsplit a parbox? (and fbox alignment, and unvbox syntax)

Tags: tex-core, boxes

I was trying to experiment with the code in this answer: [Breakable vboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes/167543#167543), and I got something I didn't expect; consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\pagecolor{yellow!10}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\def\shouldUseParbox{1} % comment to undefine

\newbox\mybox
\ifx\shouldUseParbox\undefined%
  %
  \setbox\mybox=\vbox{%
    \rightskip=35mm%
    \lipsum[2-4]
  }
  %
\else% \shouldUseParbox defined:
  %
  \setbox\mybox=\vbox{%
    \parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{%
      \lipsum[2-4]
    }%
  }
  %
\fi

First bit here:
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

% \copy\mybox
\hskip-1\parindent %\fbox will indent;
\fbox{\copy\mybox} %ok

\newbox\myboxtemp
\setbox\myboxtemp=\vsplit\mybox to 0.3\textheight

Split bit here:

% \copy\myboxtemp % ok
% \unvbox\myboxtemp % ok; same out as \copy in this case
\hskip-1\parindent %\fbox will indent;
\fbox{\copy\myboxtemp}

remains here:

\hskip-1\parindent %\fbox will indent;
\fbox{\copy\mybox}

% \setbox\myboxtemp=\unvbox\myboxtemp % "! A <box> was supposed to be here." ??
% \fbox{\unvbox\myboxtemp} % "! Missing } inserted." ??

\end{document}
```

If I want to `\vsplit` a parbox placed in a vbox (`\shouldUseParbox` is active, as in the MWE), then I get this (`lua-visual-debug`) output (click for full res):

[image: minitestA.png]

... which is totally unexpected: there is nothing on the first page - and I cannot really tell if the boxes are split, even if the framebox indicates that is the case; in any case, the boxes aren't interleaved with the rest of the text.

Now, if `\shouldUseParbox` is inactive - which means contents directly in a vbox with rightskip (as in the answer posted above), then all works as expected (click for full res):

[image: minitestB.png]

My questions are:

1. Why can I not vsplit a parbox (in a vbox)? All I know is `\parbox` is a LaTeX command, while `\vsplit` and rest are TeX core... What should one do if one need to split `\parbox` material?
2. You can see I have to "unindent" (with `\hskip-1\parindent`), so that the `\fbox` output is at the same position, as when fbox isn't used - why is this so?
3. Why can I use syntax like `\fbox{\copy\myboxtemp}` - but I cannot use `\fbox{\unvbox\myboxtemp}` ?? (I thought the effect of `\unvbox` was the same as `\box` and `\copy`, but apparently not?)

Comment: You can't apply `\vsplit` to `\vbox{\vbox{...}}` either. A `\vbox` is treated as a single object (unless it is `\unvbox`ed, but you can't `\unvbox` a `\parbox`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\vsplit` splits a vbox at a legal breakpoint in the vertical list in that box. The vertical list in `\mybox` only contains a single unbreakable item the `hbox` from the one line paragraph that contains your parbox in its first line.

All latex box commands start with `\leavevmode` so they start a paragraph with the normal indent, center in a center environment etc. If you put a tex primitive box onto the vertical list it is placed directly without any paragraph positioning.

`\unvbox` unboxes a box placing its contents on the current vertical list (and generates an error if the current list is horizontal) `\box`  and `\copy` places the box itself on the current horizontal or vertical list.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @DavidCarlisle - I had no idea about these intricacies, until now. Cheers!