# Authors biography for Inderscience journals

Tags: packages, journal-publishing, journal, biography

I would like to create a document following the Indersciences templates. The problem is: the authors biographies have to appear in the title page and the top of the second page, but when compiling the following code shows only the part of biography belonging to the title page. The title page is a singlecolumn ended after the biographies. The rest of the document from Introduction is a two columns...

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \documentclass{doublecol-new}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,upgreek}
%\usepackage[margin=0.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[total={7in,9.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot]{geometry}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}

%\newcommand{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}
%\newcommand{\ee}{\end{eqnarray}}
%\newcommand{\nn}{\nonumber}

\theoremstyle{TH}{
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corrolary}[lemma]{Corrolary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{claim}[lemma]{Claim}
\newtheorem{stheorem}[lemma]{Wrong Theorem}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
}

\theoremstyle{THrm}{
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{scheme}{Scheme}
}

\theoremstyle{THhit}{
\newtheorem{case}{Case}[section]
}

\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,colorlinks=true} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL,
morekeywords={PREFIX,skos,rdf,rdfs,owl},
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
commentstyle=\color{dkgreen}}
\makeatletter

\def\Reals{\mathbb{R}}
\def\Ints{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\Nats{\mathbb{N}}

\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
\JOURNALNAME{\TEN{\it Int. Journal, Vol. \theVOL, No. \theISSUE, \thePUBYEAR\hfill\thepage}}%
\def\tc{\textcolor{red}}

%\def\BottomCatch{%
%\vskip -10pt
%\thispagestyle{empty}%
%\begin{table}[b]%
%\NINE\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}%
%\\[-12pt]
%Copyright \copyright\ 2012 Inderscience Enterprises Ltd. & &%
%\end{tabular*}%
%\vskip -30pt%
%%%\vskip -35pt%
%\end{table}%
%%\def\tc{\textcolor}{red}
%} \makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\thispagestyle{plain}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\LRH{Author 1 et~al.}

\RRH{inderscience journal}

\VOL{x}

\ISSUE{x}

\PUBYEAR{xxxx}

%\BottomCatch

%\CLline

%\subtitle{}

\title{paper Inderscience template}

\authorA{Author 1*}
\affA{Department of Computer Science,\\ University 1,\\ City 1, Country1 \\
E-mail: author1@gmail.com\\
*Corresponding author}
\authorB{author2}
\affB{Department of Computer Science,\\ University2,\\ City 2, Country2 \\
E-mail: author2@gmail.com}
\authorC{author3}
\affC{School of Informatics and Computer Science,\\ University3,\\ City 3, \\Country3 \\
E-mail: author3@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper,    
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
 this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
this is the abstract of this paper, this is the abstract of this paper, 
\end{abstract}

\KEYWORD{latex, paper, Inderscience}
\REF{to this paper should be made as follows: Author1., Author2. and Author3.(xxx) paper Indersciencetemplate', \it {Int. J. of XXXXXXX}, Vol..~x, No.~x, pp.xxx--xxx.}


\begin{bio}

  Author1 is  blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla   
\noindent Author2 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla 
\noindent Author3 blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla 

\end{bio}


\maketitle



\section{Introduction}
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla 

\end{document}
```

For more explanation: I would like to get something like

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't do stuff like `\newcommand{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}`. It makes puppies cry.

Comment: Please give us pointers where to find `doublecol-new.cls` and reformat your example using package `blindtext` or `lipsum`.

Comment: I've used the template without any personal modification

Comment: thank you Johannes, the link is towards the whole package, http://www.inderscience.com/info/inauthors/author_templates.php  
you have to download the A4 LaTex format

Comment: And `eqnarray` is outdated

Comment: thank you Christian, however, i've used the template without any modification

Comment: @jojo: That's the general problem: Templates are often outdaten and/or ill-designed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer even if I delete eqnarray there is no change...the problem persists...

Comment: Before we go into further detail here, Have you read *Do i need to use one* in the link above?

Comment: @jojo: I did not say that `eqnarray` is the cause of your problems, just that it's outdated

Comment: @Johannes_B if I understand, I can not localize any pointer toward the class, so I do share the link from where I've download my template that's all.

Comment: You may like to contact Inderscience at support@inderscience.com with the full details of the issue and any relevant files attached, so that we can assist you with this. Kind regards,
Darren
Information Administrator
Inderscience Publishers

Comment: @DarrenSimpson and jojo: Any progress on this? Could someone post an answer to this, please?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - I think http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes might be an integrateable solution. I am not a TeX expert and I am out of tinkering time, but I think the difficulty is in the  bio environments dependency on `\newbox` and the fact that it is not easily splitable, I think a TeX programmer would have no problem integrating the two code blocks. If a LaTeX solution was an option, I can think of many ways to achieve this appearance in a template, but I assume you were focusing on the TeX aspect of the box split in which case I may not have told you anything new...

Comment: @EngBIRD To be honest, I am not focussing on nothing here. I just [put a bounty](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6207) as this topic is still open and we got an "I am having this problem, too" post from a new user. If you can get what the OP wants by a LaTeX solution, just post it. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I kind of ran out of space in the first comment I left, but I should specify that my plan  for a LaTeX solution would avoid or renew significant portions of the inderscience template.  Before I post, I would just want to confirm whether this would be valid or if the spirit of this specific question (and the requirements of the new user who said "me too") requires fixes specific to the template... a concept I am not quite sure how to accommodate because even if I were to post a fix to the cls file, there's no guarantee the publisher would integrate it, so it's not really solved

Comment: @EngBIRD True, lets wait for some reaction from the users.

Comment: I would recommend that you contact Inderscience Publishers directly via support@inderscience.com. This will allow the query to be passed onto the technical team for investigation.

Comment: I can not answer this question as it is now protected, so I will put the answer as a comment. To add biographical notes just add the text inside the commands \begin{bio} and \end{bio}. For example, \begin{bio}José Arcadio Buendía is the patriarch of the Buendía family and the founder of Macondo.\end{bio}

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm also surprised that it's been more than 4 years since the OP asked the question and the problem still exists in the template... Is the problem not solved yet?