# ! Undefined control sequence. \harvardpreambledefs

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

I have the following latex code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

%\bibliography{ijmso}
\bibliography{mybib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

 \end{thebibliography}
```

it is part of Inderscience journals template ([Authors biography for Inderscience journals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229170/99908)).
I am using natbib package. The bibliography used to work in the other template where the citation is numerical. When I tried to change it to author-year style it generates this error:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence. \harvardpreambledefs
 ! Undefined control sequence. \harvardpreambletext
```

I checked "mybib" file many times. I also tried to remove the items which can cause problem ( the ones containing special characters for example). I removed .aux .bib files and run again. I tried the to use `\cite`, `\citep`, `\citet`, but all of my attempts were unsuccessful.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you show us a complete example, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? And probably not related to the error, but I don't think you want both the `thebibliography` environment and `\bibliography`/`\bibliographystyle`, you can probably remove the environment.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up two distinct approaches to creating a formatted bibliography. You can *either* build the bibliography entirely by hand, requiring you to type `\begin{thebibliography}{10}`, lots of `\bibitem` instructions, and `\end{thebibliography}`, *or* you can use a tool such as BibTeX to create the formatted bibliography for you. If you choose the latter method, *do not under any circumstance* write `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` and `\end{thebibliography}`. Instead, provide suitable `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` directives. Your choice: one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest,  you don't want both the thebibliography environment and `\bibliography/\bibliographystyle`. So first thing I did is removing `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` and `\end{thebibliography}`.

Secondly, I downloaded the bibliography style files (.bst) from here http://www.inderscience.com/info/inauthors/author_templates.php. I installed them and I updated Miktex fndb. Suddenly, the same latex file works fine.