# Framed boxed text with "continued" text on page break

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, framed

I need to write a boxed text as like as:

[image]

Currently, I am using

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\section{Box 15...}
...
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do you need an automatic page break or do you can break the text manually?

Comment: @MartinScharrer It is better, if I get auto pagebreak, please...

Comment: Well, framed text with page break can be done easily with the `mdframed` package. Do you need the "continued" markers or can you do without them?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Sorry to trouble you, I require the auto pagebreak with "continued" marked also too by auto. able to understand the pain, but pl help...

Comment: No problem, just needed to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [egregs answer to "Breakable vboxes"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20903/2975) I coded the following environment. It collects its vertical input and then breaks it using plainTeX's internal breaking mechanism (`\vsplit`) and places both part in an `\fbox`. This will not work for large material which break across three pages, but this feature could be added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}% just for example text

\newbox\totalbox
\newbox\partialbox
\newdimen\partialboxdim

\newenvironment{continueframe}{%
    \advance\linewidth-2\fboxsep
    \advance\linewidth-2\fboxrule
    \hsize=\linewidth
    \partialboxdim=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\pageshrink-6pt-\baselineskip\relax
    \setbox\totalbox=\vbox\bgroup\begingroup
}{%
    \endgraf\endgroup\egroup
    \setbox\partialbox=\vsplit\totalbox to\partialboxdim
    \par\smallskip
    \hbox{\fbox{\vbox{\unvbox\partialbox}}}\nopagebreak
    \par\smallskip\mbox{}\hfill\textbf{Continued on next page}\par\pagebreak%
    \hbox{\fbox{\vbox{\noindent\textbf{Contuined from last page}\par\smallskip\unvbox\totalbox}}}%
    \par\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{continueframe}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{continueframe}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution...it's work absolutely fine for me...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Glad I could help you. Please note that my code might be less stable or supported by features of some packages as a released package like `tcolorbox` or similar. As long as it works for you it is fine, however.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `tcolorbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[2][]{%
breakable,
enhanced,
sharp corners,
colback=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=Box~\thetcbcounter:\ #2,
enlarge bottom at break by=5mm,
enlarge top at break by=5mm,
overlay first={%
    \draw[black, line width=0.5mm](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
    \node[anchor=north east] at (frame.south east) {continued on next page};
    },
overlay middle={%
    \draw[black, line width=0.5mm](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
    \draw[black, line width=0.5mm](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
    \node[anchor=north east] at (frame.south east) {continued on next page};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (frame.north west) {continued from next page};
    },
overlay last={%
    \draw[black, line width=0.5mm](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
    \node[anchor=south west] at (frame.north west) {continued from next page};},
#1
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{mybox}{Combined off-springs size theories}
\lipsum[3-16]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may be of some help to you.

The `continue` package prints "continuation" marks on pages of multipage documents. The marks can be defined as you wish and started and stopped at any point. To read the manual `> texdoc continue`.

Comment: Thanks for the continue package, will look into this, and use the same...